# Error while trying to upload image in a insert post form using a database with php and mysql in after hosting the website online?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload image in a insert post form using a database with php and mysql. I hosted the website. after hosting, i tried to insert data, but it throws the following errors:

**Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/Penguins.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\vhosts\srkv9093.com\testsrkv\insert_post.php on line 75**

**Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpC2A4.tmp' to 'images/Penguins.jpg' in C:\inetpub\vhosts\srkv9093.com\testsrkv\insert_post.php on line 75**

**The code**

```
<body>
<div>
<h2><a href="index.php">Logout</a></h2> 
<h2><a href="view_posts.php">View Post</a></h2>
</div>  

<form method="post" action="insert_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="600" align="center" border="0">
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="6" bgcolor="white">
<h1>Insert New Post Here</h1>                   
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">Post Title:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">Post Author:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="author"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">Post Keywords:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="keywords"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">Post Image:</td>
<td><input type="file" name="image"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">Post Content:</td>
<td><textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Now"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>

<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$post_title = $_POST['title'];
$post_date = date('d-m-y');
$post_author = $_POST['author'];
$post_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$post_content = $_POST['content'];
$post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if($post_title=='' or $post_keywords=='' or $post_content=='' or $post_author=='' or $post_date=='') {
echo "<script>alert(Some field is empty')</script>";

exit();
}

move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "images/$post_image");

$insert_query = "insert into posts (post_title, post_date, post_author, post_image, post_keywords, post_content) values ('$post_title', '$post_date', '$post_author', '$post_image', '$post_keywords', '$post_content')";

if(mysql_query($insert_query)) {
    echo "<center><h1>Post Published Successfully!</h1></center>";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Give file permission(777) to your folder

Comment: @SunilPachlangia That would indeed solve it, might not be the safest though.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia where and how?

Comment: You might not have access to the particular directory path in windows system. check the access previledge. Infact use the other path instead of c:\windows

Comment: On your server right click on that folder there will be file permission -give that read, write, execute permission

Answer (score 0):

Just to be curious, is your website hosted in a windows server or a linux server? Only then one can answer the question comprehensively

i could have commented but apparently, someone has upped the reputation for commenting,

Comment: it is windows platform from parallels plesk.

Comment: Its all to do with permissions then, trying changing permissions to 777 and see whether it works, a nice procedure here http://support.hostgator.com/articles/plesk/plesk-administration/how-to-change-file-permissions-in-plesk

Comment: You do not have writing permissions to the folder you are trying to upload to, that's why you got to change it as above

Comment: tried that: but it says "Information: You are not allowed to change permissions for this folder."

Comment: What about giving the insert file a permision of 777?

Answer (score 0):

From your path, I guess you are working on Window host.
So, you need to set writing permission of "images" folder to the "Everyone User" account. (or at least the internet guest account)
You can refer this link for how to work. http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00427/0/Setup-correct-files-and-folders-access-permissions-efficiently.html